# Count similar words

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am having an issue with this program, I want it to only displays words in the input once and count each time they appear, however it is displaying every word entered.

for example if i enter

> "this should only only appear appear once"

then i want the program to output

```
this 1 
should 1 
only 2 
appear 2 
once 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 1000
#define COL 50

int read_input(char *str, int n);

int main(void)
{
    char str[ROW];
    char stringSeperate[ROW][COL] = { };
    const char *s= " ,.!";  

    char *p;
    int freq[ROW];
    int i = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    read_input(str, ROW);

    p = strtok(str,s);
    i = 1;

    while(p !=NULL) {
        wordCount = i;
        for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
             if (strcmp(p, stringSeperate[i]) != 0) 
                pos = 1;
            else
                pos = i;
        }
        if (pos == 1) {
            strcpy(stringSeperate[i], p);           
            freq[i++]++;

        }
        else
            freq[pos]++;
        p = strtok(NULL,s);
    }

    for ( i = 1; i <= wordCount; i++ ) {
        printf("Word: %s\t Number: %d\n",stringSeperate[i], freq[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int read_input(char *str, int n) 
{
    int ch, i = 0;

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if ( i < n ) {
            *str++ = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
    *str = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Note: you should start using array from index 0 if it is not too confusing for you.

Answer (score 1):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable `freq` having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

Initialize it like `int freq[ROW] = {0};`

Also you should

1. Change initialization of `stringSeperate` to standard: empty initlalizer is not allowed, so it should be like

```
char stringSeperate[ROW][COL] = {{0}};
```

2. Remove extra printing to match the desired output: change

```
printf("Word: %s\t Number: %d\n",stringSeperate[i], freq[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%s %d\n",stringSeperate[i], freq[i]);
```

3. Check the length of input in order not to cause buffer overrun. Change

```
if ( i < n ) {
```

in `read_input` to

```
if ( i < n - 1 ) {
```

in order to make room for terminating null-characteer.